# QUERY returning row number and substring of SELECT

Tags: sql, google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheet I have such table:

```
A          B   C
----------------
One [0]    3   2
Two [1]    6   0
Three [5]  1   1
Four [3]   1   2
Five [2]   1   0
```

I would like to generate `SORT()` or `QUERY()` which will return a two-column table sorted by a sum of B and C. Also the A column should be substringed to drop last four characters.
So the result should be:

```
Two    6
One    5
Four   3
Three  2
Five   1
```

I tried with `SELECT MID(A,1,-5), (B+C) ORDER BY B+C` but the executions is pretty bad. All suggestions welcome! Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by, "the executions is pretty bad"? The execution time is bad?

Comment: I meant it didn't work at all :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, also try (in google spreadsheet)

```
=query({ArrayFormula(regexextract(A2:A, "^(.+) \[")), B2:C}, "Select Col1, sum(Col2)+sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 order by sum(Col2)+sum(Col3) label sum(Col2)+sum(Col3)''",0)
```

or, depending on your locale:

```
=query({ArrayFormula(regexextract(A2:A; "^(.+) \["))\ B2:C}; "Select Col1, sum(Col2)+sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 order by sum(Col2)+sum(Col3) label sum(Col2)+sum(Col3)''";0)
```

Also see [this example spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zrXgGEMbVshQJcYCwsEdbEO5rrJBIU3ZowoaWUw4dH0/edit#gid=0)

Comment: That's great but please tell me one thing. When I try to transform this to my other spreadsheet where are use ; instead of , to separate arguments, then I get the error 'QUERY: NO_COLUMN: Col2'.

Comment: @friedman: I updated my answer with the formula for your locale.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

```
=QUERY(B2:D7,"Select B,SUM(C)+SUM(D) group by B order by SUM(C)+SUM(D) desc label SUM(C)+SUM(D) 'SUM'")
```

[image]

If you are new to SQL ,

- Group By Clause : Whenever we use aggregate functions such as MAX,
  MIN, SUM,COUNT,AVG we will be using GROUP BY clause.
- **Label** is used to rename the column name like the AS keyword in SQL.
- ORDER BY clause is used to sort desc or asc.

[Example Spreadsheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xZ2mySqaC6Q4VwbS2Osa5BQO60boAtnGorJRhCb8piw/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Thank you, Harsha! This works great. With one additional question which I have forgotten in opening post -- is there a possibility to number the result rows? To get for example '1: Two', '6'; '2: One', '5' and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL, try this:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(A,LEN(A)-4) AS Col1
    ,(B+C) AS Col2    
FROM table    
ORDER BY Col2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql You an use sugstrin_index because your a string part is not fixed lenght

```
 select SUBSTRING_INDEX(a,' ',1) as A , b+c as C
 from your_table
 order by C DESC
```

fro sqlserver you can use substring

```
 select SUBSTRING(a, 1, instr(String," ") -1) as A , b+c as C
 from your_table
 order by C DESC
```